Considerations for UK / USA operation
I'm just getting into this. I'm currently based in the US and am studying for my ARRL Technician exam. I'd like to start listening in, so I'm in the market for my first radio.
One wrinkle in that I'm originally from the UK, frequently travel back, and may move back there at some point
Without getting into recommendations for specific products...
Are there any considerations I should keep in mind when shopping for a radio, if I want to be able to operate it in both the US and UK?

Power feels like the obvious one, but it looks like DC PSUs are fairly normal.

I would imagine that the bands etc are necessarily compatible, but perhaps that's not a fair assumption?


And I'm sure there are other factors I've not even thought of yet.
What should I watch out for?

The band plans are different for 80m, 60m and 40m. In particular, a lot of transceivers have hard-lock on the transmission frequencies on 60m, and they are PITA. I would recommend double checking actual frequency ranges the transceiver can actually transmit against both US and UK band plans, particularly for 60m. The US 60m band plan is also in the process of changing based on the ITU/WRC decision, but we don't know exactly how it will resolve. Either way, do not buy JA models. JA has mroe restrictive band plans and requires unhackable freq locks.  Most of those diode bridge mods won't work.

For most bands, either the allocation is the same, or the US has the bigger allocation, so you're probably best off getting US equipment. As of 2024, and to the best of my knowledge:

160m: US has 1800-2000 kHz, UK has 1810-2000 kHz.
80m: US has 3500-4000 kHz, UK has 3500-3800 kHz, as does Region 1 in general.
60m: the allocations are basically incompatible.
40m: US has 7000-7300 kHz, UK has 7000-7200 kHz, as does Region 1 in general.
20m through 10m: same band edges, even if the bandplan is different.
6m: US has 50-54 MHz, UK has 50-52 MHz, as does Region 1 in general.
4m: UK has an allocation, US doesn't.
2m: US has 144-148 MHz. UK has an ordinary amateur band from 144-146 MHz (like Region 1 in general), and a limited allocation, only for digital modes and only with a variance, from 146-147 MHz.
70cm: US has 420-450 MHz, UK has 430-440 MHz, as does Region 1 in general.

So if you use US-banded equipment in the UK you'll have pretty much everything except 60m and 4m. If you use equipment for a UK or European market there's a good chance you'll be locked out of significant chunks of the US amateur bands. At the very least you'll want to pay closer attention to the specs on any radios you buy on that side of the ocean.

This is wonderful - thank you!

One problem is the FM repeaters in the UK/Europe (and most places in the world) use 12.5 kHz channels (a.k.a. 2.5 kHz deviation, narrowband), while US hams specifically are stuck on 25 kHz (5 kHz deviation, wideband).
Many radios made by the Japanese ham vendors (Yaesu, Icom, Kenwood) either are stuck on 25 kHz, or often they merely cut deviation but don't have the proper RX filter.
Commercial radios normally support both via a setting, and so do commercial-derived radios (e.g. AnyTone, Baofeng).
This does not affect digital modes like DMR, as all common protocols are designed for 12.5 kHz or narrower.

Interesting! I'd be on the fence between Baofeng and Yaesu (lower end for my first radio) so this might tip the balance

This has been downvoted, but I (a novice) am not sure why. Is this incorrect/flawed advice? Should I disregard it entirely?

All of my UHF/VHF radios support both of these bandwidths and channel spacing.  If you get new equipment (made in the last 20y) this should not be an issue.  But by all means, do check the manual before you buy.  I would and do.

@user10489 No, for example the Yaesu FT-70D does not support 12.5 kHz, so it certainly is an issue in the last 20 years. If the radio does pure analog FM demodulation, it will require a different filter and the ham manufacturers won't bother. Commercial radios use DSP demod, so it's simple for them.

@user71659, I think your answer is being downvoted because it states "US hams are specifically stuck on 25 kHz" when there's plenty of equipment that is in fact nfm capable. So it's not completely wrong but it does seem misleading and even a bit curmudgeonly. Perhaps you might edit it?

Regardless, the advice from @user10489 to "check the manual before you buy" is worthwhile!!

@webmarc The fact that hams don't want to hear is the rest of the ham world narrowbanded, Part 90 in the US narrowbanded, but US hams can't cause Icom, Yaesu and Kenwood cheaped out.

Its nice to have examples of radios that don't.  Like I said, none of the ones I own have that issue.  But I probably read the manual and saw some other critical feature that was also missing and didn't buy it.
